# Select2 - make it readonly (not disabled!) from js

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

How can I dynamically make a select2 combobox read-only?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```js
$('...').attr({'readonly': 'readonly'}).trigger('change.select2');
$('...').attr({'readonly': 'readonly'}).trigger('change');
$('...').select2().enable(false);
```

Comment: .select2("readonly", true)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See: http://select2.github.io/select2/

I did it with:

```
$("#modelname-fieldname").select2({disabled:'readonly'});
```

Where:

- `modelname-fieldname` is as in: `$form -> field($modelname, "fieldname") -> widget(Select2::classname(), [ ... ]);`
- `readonly` is true, false or a string `readonly`

Optionally you can change the cursor when hovering over the `select2` field.

Comment: This is not the correct answer any more. Select does not have a `readonly` property and this (`.select2({disabled:readonly});`) was removed from select2 as well.
The way to do it is to disable the select (and use hidden input if you need to send the value)

Comment: The first codeblock helped me, I sat `{disabled:'readonly'}` and it worked ;)

Comment: `This is not the correct answer any more`. The question did not say for what version of select2 they were looking for a solution.

Comment: This works perfectly with 4.0.7. `$("#YourSelect").select2({ disabled:'readonly' })`. Just make sure you have readonly as a string (thanks seniorpreacher).

Comment: This solution doesn't send data to form

Answer (score 49):

This is Solution for Latest `select2` (Tested With `4.0.7`) using `css only`

```
/*Select2 ReadOnly Start*/
    select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container {
        pointer-events: none;
        touch-action: none;
    }

    select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container .select2-selection {
        background: #eee;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container .select2-selection__arrow, select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container .select2-selection__clear {
        display: none;
    }

/*Select2 ReadOnly End*/
```

Comment: This is beautiful!

Comment: This works on 4.0.13. 
I also had to use: element.attr("readonly",<true or false>);

Comment: Nice! Thanks! I just wanted keep the arrow so I used :
`select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container .select2-selection .select2-selection__rendered {
  opacity: .5;
    }

    select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container .select2-selection__arrow{
  opacity: .35;
    }`

Comment: This worked like a charm., You need to add attribute readonly to your normal select

Comment: And if someone wants to add a specific text color, try this:

`select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container .select2-selection > .select2-selection__rendered{color: #A1A5B7 !important;}`

Answer (score 14):

Solution from [Select2 - Issue #3387 - Readonly Support](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3387#issuecomment-281481067):

```css
select[readonly].select2 + .select2-container {
  pointer-events: none;
  touch-action: none;

  .select2-selection {
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .select2-selection__arrow,
  .select2-selection__clear {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Edit: for versions `> 4.07` - as commenters below correctly pointed out:

```css
select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container {
    pointer-events: none;
    touch-action: none;

    .select2-selection {
        background: #eee;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    .select2-selection__arrow, select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container .select2-selection__clear {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you can still select the options. Also the closing tag for the first rule is way down at the end. The best solution that works for select2 is posted by @Ali Jamal

Comment: The solution from @Ali Jamal is more practical

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The `disabled` attribute is not the good way,</strike> an HTML Element using this attribute prevents the data sending of the select when form is submit.

For a production mode, I had to find and write a solution... It works with the native `readonly` attribute of the select !
**Here, applied to all select into the DOM having the Select2 mechanism** :

```
$('select[data-select2-id]').on('select2:opening', function (e) {
    if( $(this).attr('readonly') == 'readonly') { // Check if select tag is readonly.
        //console.log( 'readonly, can't be open !' );
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).select2('close'); 
        return false;
    }
    //else{ console.log( 'expandable/selectable' ); }
});
```

I've detailed it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68018583/16115276) wit a complete demo.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
.select2("readonly", true);
.select2("readonly", false);
```

Comment: Maybe you meant
    `.select2({"readonly": true});`

But it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RebelRJ/48m1739c/1/)

This is the Script used

```
    var $S1 = $("select[name=select1]");
    var $S2 = $("select[name=select2]");
  
  $('select').select2({
      width: '100%'
    });

    function readonly_select(objs, action) {
      if (action === true)
        objs.prepend('<div class="disabled-select"></div>');
      else
        $(".disabled-select", objs).remove();
    }
    $('#setreadonly').on('click', function() {
      //readonly_select($(".select2"), true);

      $S1.attr("readonly", "readonly");
   
        $S2.attr("readonly", "readonly");

    });
    $('#removereadonly').on('click', function() {
      //readonly_select($(".select2"), false);
    
        $S1.removeAttr('readonly');
    $S2.removeAttr('readonly');

    });
    $("#abc").on('submit', function() {
      alert($("#abc").serialize());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot make the select2 as readonly as per the new version

follow the link for the hack, its pure css

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55001516/9945426

Answer (score 0):

Here some basic logic for it, add **readonly-select** class to parent, so we can make CSS and jQuery logic for its children elements. please follow below code to make readonly **select2** dropdown.

```js
$('.readonly-select select').on('select2:opening', function (e) {
    if( $(this).attr('readonly') == 'readonly') {
        // Check if select tag is readonly
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).select2('close');
        return false;
    }
});
```

```css
.readonly-select .select2-container--default .select2-selection {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group readonly-select">
    <label>Contract Type</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" readonly>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Below example works for me

```
$("#mySelect2Box").select2("readonly", true);
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm working with Select 4.0 and this works well for me

```
$('#select2-element').on('select2:select', () => {
  $('#select2-element').data('select2').destroy();
  $('#select2-element').attr('readonly', true);
});
```