# How to toggle readonly to select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I tried to set readonly attribute to second select2 based on value of first select2 option.

I have my script as below:

```
<select name="Name" id="Name" style='width:45%'>
  <option value="1">disable</option>
   <option value="2">enable</option>
</select>
<select name="Name2" id="Name2" style='width:45%'>
  <option value="d">David</option>
   <option value="b">Bob</option>
</select>
```

My JS script is to set it is like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Name,#Name2').select2();
  $('#Name').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val==1)
    {
        $('#Name2').attr('readonly','readonly');
    }else
    {
        $('#Name2').removeAttr('readonly');
    }
  })
})
```

However, the script above won't be working for select2 option but for textbox is fine. ([Fiddlejs](https://jsfiddle.net/ujdbcy3d/77/))

I tried to search some sources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807096/kartik-select2-make-it-readonly-not-disabled-from-js) but it did not help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use `.prop()` to set disabled or not based on the value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#Name').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#Name2').prop('disabled', val == 1);//prop disabled

  }).change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Name" id="Name" style='width:45%'>
  <option value="1">disable</option>
   <option value="2">enable</option>
</select>
<select name="Name2" id="Name2" style='width:45%'>
  <option value="d">David</option>
   <option value="b">Bob</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. how can I use `readonly` instead of `disabled`? because I would need to submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are not going to work with the updated versions of select2,

follow the link for the hack

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55001516/9945426

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method like this
    `$('#Name2').prop("disabled", true)`   for disable    and
    `$('#Name2').prop("disabled", false)`  for  enabling select2.

Here is the [(Fiddlejs)](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikcse20/ujdbcy3d/78/)

Comment: Thanks. Beside `disabled` can I use `readonly`? because I would need to submit the form.