# How make select2 readonly?

Tags: html, jquery-select2, readonly

I know that "readonly" feature does not exist for select2. Please check [here](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3387).
How do I achieve that?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks. 
Note: I cant use disabled. If I use disabled, I will not get the list of selected value.

Comment: have you read the all thread? here is a solution https://jsfiddle.net/ujdbcy3d/14/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess that issue is resolved or may be available for higher version as this worked for me.

Please go through the example to make a select2 readonly here: [Select 2](http://select2.github.io/select2/)

In js code:

```
$("select").select2("readonly", true);
```

You can put your own CSS like:

```
.select2-container.select2-container-disabled .select2-choice {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-color: #a8a8a8;
}
```

Comment: For select2 v4 readonly solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55001516/1209239

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
  disabled: true
});
```

Render a disabled attribute after the page loads resolved for me.

A reminder, a field with the disabled attribute is not sent on forms

Answer (score 3):

as the question says: **How to make select2 readonly?**, and as the user pointed out: **the function "readonly" does not exist for select2**. According to the select2 team developers: [read this.](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3387#issuecomment-104961591)

I just want to add a couple of things:

- disabled is not the same as readonly! be careful.
- `$(element).select2({ disabled: true });` only works on versions prior to V4. In fact the answer marked as correct refers to V3.

Having said that, I want to share a simple suggestion:

- destroy the element and make it readonly. `$(element).select2('destroy').attr("readonly", true)`
- if you need it available again you can always call him again. `$(element).select2()`

tip:

- if you want it to look like the previous element, just remove the default css style: `$(element).select2('destroy').attr("readonly", true).css({'-moz-appearance': 'none','-webkit-appearance': 'none'});`

Comment: Simple and beautiful

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('select option:selected').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

**EDIT**:

For those using Select 2 version 4+, the new way to do it should be:

```
$("select").prop("disabled", true); // instead of $("select").enable(false);
```

After clarifying the question, this is the right way to do it:

```
$('select').select2().enable(false);
```

Comment: If is disabled, it will still be sent in the form data? guess not?

Answer (score 1):

After few tests trying to block *expanding*/*opening* of the  Select2 items, I've found the way to apply a listener on each natives select tags having Select2 attribute id... and detect on opening event if the native tag is `readonly`.

```
$('select[data-select2-id]').on('select2:opening', function (e) {
    if( $(this).attr('readonly') == 'readonly') { // Check if select tag is readonly.
        console.log( 'readonly, can't be open !' );
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).select2('close'); 
        return false;
    }else{
        console.log( 'expandable/selectable' );
    }
});
```

For more custom on the Select2, we can add some CSS ...

```
select[readonly] ~ .select2.select2-container .selection [role="combobox"] {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
45deg
, #b4d2e4, #b4d2e4 10px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 10px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 20px) !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 1px rgba
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // Implement Select2
  $( 'select' ).select2({
      placeholder: "Saisissez un mot pour aide à saisie",
      tags: true, // allow create new
      width: '100%'
  });

  // Just extra button to swap readonly
  $('#button_demo_2').off().on( 'click',function(e){
    console.log( $('#select_demo_2').attr('readonly') );
    if( typeof( $('#select_demo_2').attr('readonly') ) == 'undefined' ){
      $('#select_demo_2').attr('readonly','readonly');
    }else{
      $('#select_demo_2').removeAttr('readonly');
    }
  } );
  
  
  // Demo code...
  $('select[data-select2-id]').on('select2:opening', function (e) {
      if( $(this).attr('readonly') == 'readonly') {
          console.log( 'can not open : readonly' );
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).select2('close');
          return false;
      }else{
          console.log( 'can be open : free' );
      }
  });


});
```

```css
*{
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}
body {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #215a82;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,#215a82 0%,#152135 100%) no-repeat;

    display: -webkit-box !important;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
    -webkit-box-align: center !important;
    -ms-flex-align: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute !important;
    justify-content: space-around !important;
}
.container {
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
}

div[role="box"]{
    padding:1rem;
    margin:2rem
    display: block;
}

pre {
    line-height: 1rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    color: white;
}


select[readonly] ~ .select2.select2-container .selection [role="combobox"] {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #dadada, #dadada 10px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.66) 10px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.66) 20px) !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 1px #77859133;
}

input{
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<main class="container">

<div role="box">
  <pre></pre>
  <select class="form-control inputFocusable" id="select_base" name="select_base" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="A">Item A</option>
    <option value="B">Item B</option>
    <option value="C">Item C</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div role="box">
  <pre>readonly</pre>
  <select class="form-control inputFocusable" id="select_demo_1" name="select_demo_1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" readonly>
    <option value="A">Item A</option>
    <option value="B">Item B</option>
    <option value="C">Item C</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div role="box">
  <pre>readonly="readonly"</pre>
  <select class="form-control inputFocusable" id="select_demo_2" name="select_demo_2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" readonly="readonly">
    <option value="A">Item A</option>
    <option value="B">Item B</option>
    <option value="C">Item C</option>
  </select>
</div>



</main>

<div role="box">
  <pre>readonly ?</pre>
  <input id="button_demo_2" type="button" value="Fix / Remove">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make the select read-only, you should use

```
$('select').select2({
  readonly: true
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot make the select2 as readonly as per new version of select2,

follow the link for the css hack, it works like a charm

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55001516/9945426

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(".example_element").css("pointer-events","none");
```

Answer (score 0):

There workaround using select2 and standard select.

JS :

```
if (this.value == "") {
  $("#vessel").select2(); // initialize select2
  $("#vessel").val(""); //emptying value, optional
  $("#vessel").trigger("change"); // from select2 doc, you need notify any JS components that the value changed
} else {
  // check whether Select2 has been initialized on DOM element
  if ($("#vessel").hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
    $("#vessel").select2("destroy"); 
    // remove the Select2 widget from the target element. It will revert back to a standard control
  } 
  $("#vessel").val(this.value);
  $("#vessel").css("background-color", "#E9ECEF");
  $("#vessel").css("pointer-events", "none");
  $("#vessel").attr("tabIndex", -1);
  // 3 lines code above make select to readonly
}
```

I'm using CSS to make select to readonly.
When `this.value` is empty, then `<select>` using select2 library and user can select option. Otherwise, select using standard select and user can't select option.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
$("#id_example").select2({readonly:true});
```

Disabled not send data on POST action.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#element_id').select2().readonly(true);
```

This can be define your element readonly and still send your POST data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).